# Integrating a calculator into a wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I have made a custom calculator for a client. Now he wants to integrate it into a wordpress site and needs help. The calculator is pure HTML+CSS+JS and no PHP code.

He wants the calculator to appear as part of the page's main content (not in the sidebar). What is this regarded in wordpress, a plugin? a widget? Where can I find information about integrating such tools in wordpress?

P.S. He wants the calculator to appear in a page at http://site.com/services/calc/ and the page has other content besides the calculator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy/messy way would be to just drop it as a code snippet into a page. 
See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript#Javascript_in_Posts

The more difficult but ultimately more reusable way would be to build this as a plugin, called via a shortcode like [calc].
See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Hope this helps!

-æ.